# Laravel custom validator function not being called

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to add a custom rule for validator, but it's not working at all, the function is not even called. I took this from documentation(https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules):

In AppServiceProvider::boot I have this:

```
Validator::extend('foo', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
   return false;
});
```

and In my controller I have this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'myField' => 'foo',
]);
```

The validator doesn't fail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. My json was wrong and if input value is null(or empty) then custom Validator::extend rules won't be checked. So solution would be

```
Validator::extendImplicit('foo', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return $value == 'foo';
});
```

or $request field that isn't empty